# Spring's JPARepository and @Scheduled return stale data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have simple application that read data from a Postgres view periodically.
For that I've setup a spring boot(v3) application like the below:

**Order Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_view")  //order_view is a view
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Order implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "numeric")
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "CLIENT_NAME")
    private String clientName;
}
```

**Order Repo:**

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
   
}
```

**Order Service:**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
   
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Order> getAllOrders() {
        return orderRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Scheduler Service:**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SchedulerService {

   private final OrderService orderService;

   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void readFromDB() {
        List<Order> orders= orderService.getAllOrders();
        log.debug("DATA: {}", orders);
}
```

Things working fine, but the problem is that when the view data is updated (via another application for example), the output of `readFromDB()` is still giving me the old data, while querying the view directly giving me the up to date data.

Even I created a rest controller as below to call the OrderService directly, and the surprise that the controller also returns a stale data, not the new:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/orders")
    public List<Order> getAllData() {
        return orderService.getAllOrders();
 }
```

I only get the new data after restarting the app and but also, when the view updated, the output is not reflected the view output.

Now, when I remove `@Scheduled` annotation (disabling the scheduler), the controller working as expected and return up to date data!

I've tried many suggestions such as calling `entiyManager.clear()` inside the `@Scheduled` method without any luck. Also, I've added `@Transactional()` with different propagation and isolation types also without any luck.

**UPDATE#1**

I've re-tested the issue with a different entity mapped to a regular table instead of mapping to view and the issue no longer occurs.

Also, I query the view directly via `JdbcTemplate` from the `@Scheduled` method and now I'm getting the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are misusing Hibernate in this situation, because Hibernate doesn't expect that anything else to change the data. Hibernate is not primarily used to read data that is being updated by something else. At least this is my personal opinion.

If you have a small application that does only that little thing with the DB I recommend you to do not use Hibernate.

But I think your problem is in Hibernate caches:

- if you enabled [Hibernate L2 cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#second-level-cache) disable it
- you can try to clear [session cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#session-cache-management) using `detach()` and `clear()` methods from the [Hibernate L1 cache](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#persistence-contexts)
- or you can try to use the [stateless session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html#stateless-sessions)

I hope you solve this annoying problem!

Comment: The app here only for demonstration, but in reality, it's a bigger with many crud requirements.
Regarding the Hibernate, I didn't enable L2 caching, just a simple app with the sane defaults properties. Also, I've mentioned that I've try `clear()` from the `EntityManager`.
Please note as I mentioned in the update, everything is fine with if the entity is mapped to a table, the issue is only with the entity that had mapped to a DB view.

Comment: @mohmf, this is very interesting, but I didn't find any helpful information on this issue related to interacting with the view. I think you should try `stateless session` and get the data using the bare `createQuery()` method.

Comment: I'm now starting to believe the issue may be from my view, I create another simple view and things work fine when I update the source table of the new view via DBeaver. The other view (which has the issue) is quite complex and it's a kind of aggregation view to bringing some statistics and the data that the view reflecting is been updated via another microservice,
But really what drives me nut:  
1- When I query the view via `select` using DBeaver, it bring me the updated data while the app not.  
2- When I comment out `@Scheduled` annotation, the controller works as expected!

Comment: @mohmf, thanks for the news. OMG! Turns out Spring's built-in scheduler affects Hibernate's behavior. I never liked this tool for many reasons. The best alternative is to use [Quartz](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html)